# httpd AddType directive

Tags: httpd

Is there a way to just have php parsed in a single file rather than in all files ending in a particular extension?

For example, I know that

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

will parse all .html files using the php parsing engine

But I want to only parse abc.html and not anythingelse.html
I am thinking this is the directive

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php abc.html
```

but it does not work like I want it too.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) directive inside a [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) or [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) container to only apply it to specific files.

Comment: That was exactly the answer. I tested it and it did just what I needed. Thanks joschi.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **mod_rewrite (.htaccess file)** for the trick instead ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ abc.php [L]
```

So when people go to www.yourdomain.com/abc.html they will actually be seeing abc.php, you can aswell hide abc.php somewhere else.

This is a internal redirection so only you would know where abc.php is.